# Hibernate Criteria Projection

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria, restrictions

Well as the question title says, I am trying to make a projection criteria querying only couple of the table attributes.

So I have a Person Table/class and it has about 40 attributes. I want my criteria to get dynamical number of attributes, lets say 10, 11 or 12 (SQL terms `select firstname, lastname from person`) and I was doing it like this:

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
crit.setCacheable(true);
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.property("id"));
Criterias c = null;
 for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        Attribute attr = checked.elementAt(i);
        switch (attr) {
            case LASTNAME:
                projList.add(Projections.property("lastName"));
                c = enumMap.get(attr);
                if (c.isChanged()) {
                    String tmp = (String) c.getAnswer();
                    tmp = tmp.replace('*', '%');
                    crit.add(Restrictions.like("lastName", tmp));
                    crit.addOrder(Order.asc("lastName"));
                }
            case ...THE REST .....
            }
    crit.setProjection(projList);
    retList = crit.list();
    tx.commit();
    return retList;
```

and it gives back that the `retList` elements are not from the `Person.class`:

> INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (UserGroupManagerApp.java127) - [Ljava.lang.Object;@14b9b80
>   FATAL [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Login.java78) - java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to usergroupmanager.model.db.Person
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to usergroupmanager.model.db.Person

Please help, for now I am listing all the 40+ attr, and it takes up querying time and I do not like it. I am looking also an alternative solution which will help me solve this. I read about `ResultTransformer` but havent found how to use it in my case.

Comment: What is the definition of retList

Comment: List retList = null; at start, i tested it with generics now List<Person> retList = null and same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   usergroupmanager.model.db.Person

Says in clean words `Object[]` cannot be cast to `Person`. When you do a projection, you will get the attributes you selected as an array of objects instead of a hydrated entity.

Your code is missing the declaration of `retlist`. I guess it's a raw `List` which you cast to a `List<Person>` somewhere. Just replace that with `List<Object[]>`.

Comment: thank you, i figured it out eventually but it was frustrating at that time.. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 6):

You can use criteria.setResultTransformer()

There's some Transformers provided in Hibernate. If your Person has not any association use this:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Person.class));
```

But if Person has any association, consider use Seimos at http://github.com/moesio/seimos

A lot of code could be saved if you use it instead Criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a projection in Hibernate you are not querying all the data Hibernate needs to create the objects. Thus Hibernate cannot create the objects.

Thus the query from a projection just returns an array of the SQL returned from the query ie it returns a s List and you access the fields as plain entries in that array.